# Is the quotient map of a Lie group proper? Can you take a compact set of representatives?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a lie group, $\Gamma < G$ a discrete subgroup.

Is it true that the canonical map $p: G\to G/\Gamma$  necessarily proper (that is, pre-images of compact sets are compact)?

I know that it is true for compact $\Gamma$, and could not make the proof work for a discrete subgroup. This is false for a general topological space.

(I really don't know if it's true or not, I just thought it would be useful if it is).

Actually, I would also like to get any recommendations for basic textbooks on Lie Groups / Topological Groups that cover such "basic" topological concepts.

**P.S:**

I understand that my question is really not interesting in the current form (should have not asked it, too trivial), but let me ask what I really needed (which could also be trivial?):

Given $K\subset G/\Gamma$ compact, is there necessarily $K_1 \subset G$ compact such that $p(K_1)=K$?

That is I don't require the pre-image to be compact, just that I'm able to take a compact set of representatives. As far as I can tell, the counterexample $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ fails here.

Comment: It is proper if and only if $\Gamma$ is finite.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: That's good to know (and makes sense), I'll try to prove the difficult part later today :) thx

Comment: Yes, the answer to the new question is positive; just follow the proof I have here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321254/a-corollary-of-proper-action/2323266#2323266

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just take $G=(\mathbb R,+)$ and $\Gamma=\mathbb Z$. Then $p^{-1}\bigl(0+\mathbb{Z}\bigr)=\mathbb Z$, which is not compact.

Comment: Thanks. you got my upvote, sorry for the trivial question. I did update the question.